# Can the polarity of an electromagnet be same at both ends?

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across this question:
[image: Electromagnet AB]

The question asks to determine the polarity of the ends of the electromagnet.
On applying the clock rule, the polarity of end A comes to be South while that of end B also comes out to be South. Am I doing something wrong or is the question itself wrong?

Also, I would like to know whether this is possible practically or not.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer. The essence of Qwerty's answer is, "[I] don't know what will happen." Meanwhile, Wolphram jonny got it right. when you energize your magnet, it basically becomes a funny-shaped bar magnet with its north pole at the closed end, and its south pole spread across the two "prongs" at the slotted end. Qwerty was right about _one_ thing: The coils of _any_ electromagnet will "try to move" when you switch it on, and if you can force enough current through it, you can make it explode. (Google for "coin shrinker." The exploding magnet is part of the fun!)

Comment: @SolomonSlow I was just ignorant of length of my answer, so that "don't know" was getting highlighted, questioner got the key idea of 'how it's equivalent to joining like poles of magnets'(since the question is from kind of exam I have got through earlier I knew standard answer) consider elaborated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have the same polarity, the north pole is actually at the top. It is not the same as bending a permanent magnet, because the wire is not a uniformly bent spiral, due to how the wiring is made at the top, reversing the polarity.